# Photos not saving in QField

Tags: qfield

I've recently encountered a problem with photos not saving in QField (it was working in early August and I ran into this issue late August).
When "Use native camera" is toggled on the photos are not saved (everything appears to work within QField but no image file is saved to the DCIM folder or anywhere on the device). When "Use native camera" is toggled off the QField camera works and images are saved.
I wonder if it might be related to the [inability to set the default camera](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228774/how-do-we-set-the-default-camera-app-in-android-11) in Android 11?
Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Check length of db entry for name versus actualY generated photo name.